# How to detect how many times a visitor has visited a page

Tags: javascript, php, web, detect

I'm trying to code a website that can detect if a user has visited a link again.

I've tried to use cookies & sessions to detect but its worthless as soon as the client deletes his browser history!

I've tried to store the ip address with its latitude and longitude but some users can change the ip!

Is there any method else?
My website will pay to users so if I can't detect the frequent visits to a page, users can earn more illegally!

**Edit**
The visitors are not members and don't have accounts on the website
Its like they watch ads on the link which is created by a user
So i want to detect visitors visits

Comment: You can't, to be frank.

Comment: You need to have some type of login system to implement that and store the values in a database.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any ideas about the data which I have to store? Ip, latitude or what?

Answer (score 2):

If authentication is not an option, you should do what all advertisement websites do, create a fingerprint of the visitor, keep track of IP blocks (you need something like maxmind database to do that), block VPN and Proxies (there are lots of services and methods to do that), and cross your fingers and wish for minimum error margin.

Comment: How can I make a fingerprint for a user? Do you have instructions or link? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

well you can check when  your token is changed and decode it and which ever user id it is your gonna add 1 to a specific att(this att counts how many times he logged in) found in Users collection in your db or in another collection which includes this att and a forgien key for users

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that the website will pay real money to users via some kind of transfer. You can identify users by that. Check if the receiver account is old enough, if yes, probably you shouldn't hold back. These services for money transfer don't just give accounts all day

If the service does, then maybe you should use an additional factor, such as confirming a phone number, a credit card, or use other services that can tell you if a user is legit

Comment: Your idea is true but the visitor will not be a member, its like "shorten link" websites, unknow visitors see ads and the website must pay to the creator of the shortened link just once per visitor, that what I have meant, thank you very much